# Deserialize object binary to XML?

Tags: c#, xml, deserialization, xmlserializer, binaryformatter

I am having some trouble deserializing an object to XML. I am trying to deserialize something which doesn't have an empty constructor thus I need to use the BinaryFormatter? I have:

- A DLL which consists of a class I want to deserialize into XML.
- From reflecting the type I can see that it has no parameterless constructor.
- This class contains properties of which some do not have empty constructors either.

My question is, is it possible to deserialize this class into XML? I did find a way whereby I used:

- BinaryFormatter
- Loaded the contents into a stream
- Used a FileStream to write its contents but ended up with rubbish

Thanks in advance. I found something called FormatterServices... but don't know whether you could use this in conjunction with the XmlSerializer?

Comment: Have you tried **[DataContractSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractserializer.aspx)**? I'm not sure if it can serialize any class (not decorated with DataContract and its members with DataMember)

Comment: This is called Serialization...

Comment: @HonzaBrestan nice that seemed to work, however you get some weird looking XML... any ideas how to dismiss the weird tags you get for each field?

Comment: Only if you have access to the class itself or you can wrap it - you need to decorate it with the attributes that I mentioned - with them you can change the tag names.

Answer (score 0):

1. Deserialize the binary data back into an object.
2. Copy your object into a surrogate object.
3. Xml serialize your surrogate object.

Assume the type of your original non-xml serializable object is "Foo"

```
[XmlRoot]
public class FooSurrogate {

     public FooSurrogate() { }; // note the empty constructor for xml deserialization

     public FooSurrogate(Foo foo) {  // this constructor is used in step 2
          // in here you copy foo's state into this object's state
          this.Prop1 = foo.Prop1; // this prop can be copied directly 
          this.Bar = new BarSurrogate(foo.Bar); // this prop needs a surrogate as well  
     } 

     [XmlAttribute]  // note your surrogate can be used to xml-format too!
     public string Prop1 { get; set; }

     [XmlElement]
     public BarSurrogate Bar { get; set; }

}

public class BarSurrogate { 
...
}
```